# Creating own float structure in C++

Tags: c++, struct, floating-point, unions

Yet my lectures in C++ at university began yet i got my first problems. Our task was it to implement a self made structure in C++ for floating points via the IEEE 754 standard:

> *Create a data structure that allows you to store a float, read its raw byte representation and its internal representation as s, e and m. Use a combination of union and bit-field-struct.
>   Write a program where a float number is assigned to the float part of the structure and the raw and s/e/m representation is printed. Use hexadecimal output for raw and m.*

What i had so far is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

union {
    struct KFloat {
        //Using bit fields for our self made float. s sign, e exponent, m mantissa
        //It should be unsigned because we simply use 0 and 1
        unsigned int s : 1, e : 8, m : 23;
    };
    //One bit will be wasted for our '.'
    char internal[33];
};

float calculateRealFloat(KFloat kfloat) {
    if(kfloat.s == 0) {
        return (1.0+kfloat.m)*pow(2.0, (kfloat.e-127.0));
    } else if (kfloat.s == 1) {
        return (-1.0)*((1.0+kfloat.m)*pow(2.0, (kfloat.e-127.0)));
    }
    //Error case when s is bigger 1
    return 0.0;
}

int main(void) {
    KFloat kf_pos = {0, 128, 1.5707963705062866};//This should be Pi (rounded) aka 3.1415927
    KFloat kf_neg = {1, 128, 1.5707963705062866};//Pi negative

    float f_pos = calculateRealFloat(kf_pos);
    float f_neg = calculateRealFloat(kf_neg);

    printf("The positive float is %f or ",f_pos);
    printf("%e\n", f_pos);

    printf("The negative float is %f or ",f_neg);
    printf("%e", f_neg);
    return 0;
}
```

The first error with this code is clearly that the mantissa is absolutely wrong but i have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Your mantissa should be an integer. Any description of IEEE that has a floating point value for the mantissa is not telling the truth.

Comment: Your requirement specifically asks for a `union`.

Comment: But how shall i implement the union? I don't know what is meant be raw and internal represantation.

Comment: raw (I guess) is float, internal is the bit fields you already have (or maybe it's the other way around). Anyway that's irrelevant to you main problem which is a bit field must be an integer, so you need formulas that assume the mantissa (or significand) is an integer.

Comment: Not seeing any C++ here

Comment: @PeterWood not helping here with being picky about the language chosen as i have to learn 70% of the language by myself. hey c++ is based on c so why not use it then :P

Comment: @Jack: One reason to use C and not C++ is that C partially defines the result of accessing a union member other than the last one stored, and C++ does not.

Comment: @John: The IEEE 754 standard does not use the word “mantissa” at all, and it defines the significand as a number represented with digits after a radix point (as well as one before), not as an integer. In subclause 3.3, it refers to “the sigificand m”, and it defines “m” as a number represented by a digit string d[0].d[1]d[2]…d[p-1] (with the original typography not reproduced in this comment).

Comment: It may be preferable to use `ldexp` to load the exponent of a floating-point value rather than `pow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please reread the task:

> Create a data structure that allows you to store a float, 
>   read its raw byte representation 
>   and its internal representation as s, e and m.

this does not mean that you should store a string

I would do this the following way:

```
union MyFloat
{
  unsigned char rawByteDataRep[4];
  unsigned int  rawDataRep;
  float         floatRep;
  struct{   // not checked this part just copied from you
   unsigned s : 1;
   unsigned e : 8;
   unsigned m : 23;
  }             componentesRep;
}
```

but be careful!
Besides the fact that this union-conversion pattern is widely used, the **C-Standard** states that the result is **undefined behaviour** if you read another unionmember than the one that was written.

Edit:
added uint32 rep

```
void testMyfloat()
{
  MyFloat mf;
  mf.floatRep = 3.14;
  printf("The float %f is assembled from sign %i magnitude 0x%08x and exponent %i and looks in memory like that 0x%08x.\n",
        mf.floatRep, 
        (int)mf.componentesRep.s, 
        (unsigned int)mf.componentesRep.m, 
        (int)mf.componentesRep.e, 
        mf.componentesRep.rawDataRep);

}
```

Comment: I think exponent shoul be signed

Comment: The behavior is not completely undefined by the C standard. It states that when a union member other than the last one stored is accessed, the bytes are reinterpreted as the new type. Obviously, the representations are somewhat implementation dependent. If one changes `unsigned int` to `uint32_t`, then the union defined in this answer is likely to work in many implementations except for the problems caused by endianness and bit-field order.

Comment: The stored exponent of an IEEE-754 binary number is always non-negative. When it is converted to the actual exponent, then it does become a signed value, by subtracting 127 (for a 32-bit `float`) from the stored value.

Comment: @Eric ah ok. as you mention it i remember the exponent with the offset.
Regarding the c standard: iam quite sure that explicitly looked up this topic, because somebody pointed me onto the undefined behaviour but i cannot find the paragraph now.

Answer (score 1):

Bruce Dawson has an excellent series of blog posts on floating point representation and arithmetic. The latest in the series, which has a bunch of links to previous posts that discusses this subject matter in detail, is [here](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/float-precision-revisited-nine-digit-float-portability/).